# The label is falling down in the list tag

Tags: html, asp.net, dhtml

```
<li><span>Test:</span>
<asp:Label style="float:right;padding-right:5px"
           runat="server"
           ID="lblTest">
</asp:Label></li>
```

I have a span and a label(I am aware its also rendered as span), somehow the static span's text is fine but the label's text falls down in the Li element....down to the bottom.
I have tried vertical align and text align, top:0, but no luck to have them in a straight line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li>
    <span>Test:</span>
    <asp:Label style="display:inline-block;" runat="server" ID="lblTest">hi</asp:Label>
</li>
```

Change your style to this:

```
style="display:inline-block;"
```

It displays the block as below

[image: Output]

## <kbd>[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dG4LE/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try this it works for me

```
<li>
    <span>Test:</span>
    <asp:Label style="padding-right:5px;display:inline;" runat="server" ID="lblTest"></asp:Label>
</li>
```